# How do I set cURL to always use the -k option?

Tags: curl, command-line

For some reason my version of darwin/bash/evn variables is not letting me co anything from the command line with https, I dunno why, but I have tried everything.

But I have found that cURL (the mean reason this is a problem for) can take a -k option or --insecure. This isn't great but its a hack that will work for now.

Could I just user alias curl='curl -k' ? I have never aliased something to overwrite a command that actually exists, will that even work?

Comment: Very bad strategy; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Aliasing commands is usually not a problem. You could also put `-k` or `--insecure` into `$HOME/.curlrc`:

```
echo insecure >> $HOME/.curlrc
```